# Firebase admin upload PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase admin to upload a 250MB video file to cloud storage.

Heres my code:

```
await bucket.upload(downloadVideoResponse.filePath, { destination, resumable: false })
```

This code throws the error:

> PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

How do I remove the file size upload limit? I've look at Firebase storage rules but I do not have any rules imposing a file size limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hints at an upload limit for non resumable files:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#size

The answer is simply as follows:

```
await bucket.upload(downloadVideoResponse.filePath, { destination, resumable: true })
```

Which seems to remove the file size limit.